# Interfacing DS18B20 through Address

Tags: c, arduino, hex

I have address of one wire device DS18b20, I want to interface it by declaring its address in an array and i want to call the initializer of the address array is onewire.select(array-Initializer) and then i want to compute the temperature, but i am getting Data = 0 0  0 0

```
#include <OneWire.h>
OneWire ds(10);
//byte address[8];
byte data[12];
//int a;
byte i;
byte address[]={0x28,0xFF,0x6C,0xEA,0x62,0x16,0x4,0xE7};  

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    ds.reset();
    ds.select(&address);
    ds.write(0x44);

    ds.reset();
    ds.select(address);
    ds.write(0xBE);

    Serial.print("DATA=");
    for (i=0;i<9;i++){
        Serial.print(" ");
        data[i]= ds.read();
        Serial.print(data[i],DEC);
        Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println();
    delay(1000);
}
```

I am also getting this error:

```
no matching function for call to 'OneWire::select(byte (*)[8])
```

Comment: How are you getting a compilation error and program result at the same time?

Comment: forgot to mention:

Comment: forgot to mention: instead of passing &address to ds.select i am passing ds.select(address) and also i also had declared the address array as byte then i am getting this 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [sources](https://github.com/lstoll/arduino-libraries/blob/master/OneWire/OneWire.cpp#L184):

```
void OneWire::select( uint8_t rom[8])
```

try:

```
uint8_t address[]={0x28,0xFF,0x6C,0xEA,0x62,0x16,0x4,0xE7};  
ds.select(address);
```

C++ is aware of variable types.

Comment: still i am getting 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0